# infinitely loop for org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker

Tags: hadoop

I am running one simple hadoop application which collect information from a 64MB file, the map finished quickly, roughly in about 2 -5 minutes, then reduce also runs fast up to 16%, then it just stopped.

This is the program output

```
11/12/20 17:53:46 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
11/12/20 17:53:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201112201749_0001
11/12/20 17:53:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 4% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 15% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 28% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 40% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 53% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 64% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 77% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 89% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 98% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
11/12/20 17:54:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 8%
11/12/20 17:54:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 16%
```

In the data node log, I see tons of same message again and again, the following is there is starts,

```
2011-12-20 17:54:51,353 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.083333336% reduce > copy (1 of 4 at 9.01 MB/s) >
2011-12-20 17:54:51,507 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.clienttrace: src: 127.0.1.1:50060, dest: 127.0.0.1:44367, bytes: 75623263, op: MAPRED_SHUFFLE, cliID: attempt_201112201749_0001_m_000000_0, duration: 2161793492
2011-12-20 17:54:54,389 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.16666667% reduce > copy (2 of 4 at 14.42 MB/s) >
2011-12-20 17:54:57,433 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.16666667% reduce > copy (2 of 4 at 14.42 MB/s) >
2011-12-20 17:55:40,359 INFO org.mortbay.log: org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@53d3cf JVM BUG(s) - injecting delay3 times
2011-12-20 17:55:40,359 INFO org.mortbay.log: org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@53d3cf JVM BUG(s) - recreating selector 3 times, canceled keys 72 times
2011-12-20 17:57:51,518 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.16666667% reduce > copy (2 of 4 at 14.42 MB/s) >
2011-12-20 17:57:57,536 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.16666667% reduce > copy (2 of 4 at 14.42 MB/s) >
2011-12-20 17:58:03,554 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.16666667% reduce > copy (2 of 4 at 14.42 MB/s) >
```

...

up to

```
2011-12-20 17:54:51,353 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.083333336% reduce > copy (1 of 4 at 9.01 MB/s) >
2011-12-20 17:54:51,507 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.clienttrace: src: 127.0.1.1:50060, dest: 127.0.0.1:44367, bytes: 75623263, op: MAPRED_SHUFFLE, cliID: attempt_201112201749_0001_m_000000_0, duration: 2161793492
2011-12-20 17:54:54,389 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.16666667% reduce > copy (2 of 4 at 14.42 MB/s) >
2011-12-20 17:54:57,433 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.16666667% reduce > copy (2 of 4 at 14.42 MB/s) >
2011-12-20 17:55:40,359 INFO org.mortbay.log: org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@53d3cf JVM BUG(s) - injecting delay3 times
2011-12-20 17:55:40,359 INFO org.mortbay.log: org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@53d3cf JVM BUG(s) - recreating selector 3 times, canceled keys 72 times
2011-12-20 17:57:51,518 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.16666667% reduce > copy (2 of 4 at 14.42 MB/s) >
2011-12-20 17:57:57,536 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.16666667% reduce > copy (2 of 4 at 14.42 MB/s) >
2011-12-20 17:58:03,554 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201112201749_0001_r_000000_0 0.16666667% reduce > copy (2 of 4 at 14.42 MB/s) >
```

Here is the code

```
package com.bluedolphin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class MyJob {
    private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);
    private final static Text word = new Text();

    public static class MyMapClass extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        public void map(LongWritable key, 
                    Text value, 
                    Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] citation = value.toString().split(",");
            word.set(citation[0]);

            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }

    public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
        private LongWritable result = new LongWritable();
        public void reduce(
                Text key, 
                Iterator<LongWritable> values, 
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;

            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }
            result.set(sum);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }


     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
            if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
              System.err.println("Usage: myjob <in> <out>");
              System.exit(2);
            }
            Job job = new Job(conf, "patent citation");
            job.setJarByClass(MyJob.class);
            job.setMapperClass(MyMapClass.class);
           // job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);
           // job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
          }

}
```

I don't know how to further troubleshooting.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Looks like the reducers are breaking in the shuffle and sort phase. It would be better if you can tell what key value pair your mappers are emitting.

Comment: I uploaded code. The reducer is really simple, I don't see it could have infinite loop. And the CPU usage seems fine, I could do other work like browsing or even install and test mahout without any feeling of slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution, in the reduce method signature, I should have been using Iterable, not Iterator. Because of that, the reduce method was actually not called. It runs fine now, but I don't know the internal reason that it hung before.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things i noticed in your code:

Since you are updating the Text object "word" in map and the LongWritable object "result" in reduce for each call to map and reduce respectively, you probably shouldn't declare them final (Although i don't see this as a problem in this case, as the objects are only changing the state).

Your code looks similar to the trivial word count, only difference is as you are just emiting one value per record in map. You could just eliminate reduce (i.e., run a map-only job) and see if you get what you expect from map.

Comment: I commented out the final for the result, like you said, I don't think matter. Then I commented out  job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class); and job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);  Seems job has its own reduce class.  So anyway, it still stuck on 16% when reducing.

Comment: In a map only job, reducer shouldn't even run. Try setting "job.setNumReduceTasks(0);" . This explicitly sets the number of reducers to 0. If you still get that error, i would encourage you to give some sample of your input.

Comment: I set the job.setNumReduceTasks(0), then only map works, and it ends successfully. The data is sample data http://www.nber.org/patents/Cite75_99.zip, extract to text file.  I noticed that after the hang, then next time I stop-all and then start-all, the namenode will not start. I have to do hadoop namenode -format to make it work again. I have two data node, one master node.  I also updated the code.

Comment: I asked you for sample data and you uploaded a 65 MB file. A sample data is may be 10-100 records of input, and if your program gives you the expected output on sample data, it should give you the expected output when running on actual data. I basically wanted to see the format of your input.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I put the real data. It is not a sample data. The format of the data is very simple, they are pairs of "CITING","CITED": 
3858241,956203
3858241,1324234
3858241,3398406
3858241,3557384
3858241,3634889

Comment: I tried a simple java program to do the same thing, the calculation finishes in seconds.... I start thinking whether hadoop is emperor's new cloth...

Comment: btw, map/reduce program with juat 10 records works fine, take about 15 sec to finish...

Comment: It should work fine in that case. You are expecting output as {"CITING", 1} for this input, and that is exactly what map produces for this input. Am i following you?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this infinity loop during the reduce work. After struggling for a day, the solution turns out to be adjust the /etc/hosts file.

It seems that the existence of the entry "127.0.1.1 your_Machine's_Name" confused the Hadoop. One proof of that would be the disability to access the slave:50060, the taskTracker on the slave machine, from the master machine.

As long as this "127.0.1.1 your_machine's_name" entry is deleted and add "your_machine's_name" at the end of the entry "127.0.0.1 localhost", my problem is gone.

I hope this observation can be helpful.